# Specifying relative paths for Template XML file in TestNG

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I am using Eclipse (Luna) with a TestNG project.

I would like to specify a relative path for my testNG.xml file, but the "Apply" box is grayed out.

I assume that this is because the path being pre-pended to the Template XML file is different than the path being pre-pended to the Output directory (above), but I cannot figure out what path that might be.

Does TestNG support relative paths for the Template XML file?  And if so, where can I find what directory the path is relative to?

[image]

Comment: /resources/testNG.xml is NOT a relative path. can you please try removing the "/" and see if that helps ? I doubt if this text field was built to support relative paths.

Comment: I have already tried both ./resources/testNG.xml and resources/testNG.xml, but neither work.   I only show /resources because it looks like the format that the output directory is specified.

Comment: Then I guess this field doesn't support relative paths, because if you see its a general configuration that is going to be applied across all projects.

Comment: please track [the similar ticket on github](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/102), i'd like to support workspace-related location for template file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now the feature is available in TestNG Eclipse Plugin [6.11.0.201703011520](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/releases/tag/6.11.0.201703011520) in release update-site: http://beust.com/eclipse, feel free to put your feedback [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/102) on github ticket.

Comment: Thank you for adding this to the ticket!